How do you generate a unique question answer pair with an LLM prompt, ensuring uniqueness every single time?
I am making a little game for Spanish learners. In this game they can play a time trial. They pick the number of questions they want to answer and start answering them. My question is on how to generate those questions. My hope was to make them unique to every game (or at least not to repetitive) so I was hoping to use an LLM, put I am having trouble not making it repeat itself every time.
What I have tried:

Asking it to make it unique: Only works a bit but gets repetitive every 3 questions or so.
Modifying temperatures: Didn't do much, and I don't want it to start generating to many incorrect Q/A pairs.
Providing a random seed in the prompt to try and create some randomness (10 characters): Worked a bit but gets repetitive every 4 questions or so.

P.S. I am open to other options for unique question answer pair generation other than using an LLM.
